Is it safe to interrupt fsck?
I'm using a 100TB(~2TB used) ext4 HDD for data, but its primary gpt partition table was corrupted so i repair it with the backup partition table via gdisk.
And i tried to mount this disk but failed, so i tried  fsck -y, but it may need several days.
fsck output looks like every inode bitmap is in the wrong block group.
Relocating group xxx's block bitmap to xxx
Relocating group xxx's inode bitmap to yyy
Relocating group xxx's inode table to zzz

So is it safe to interrupt fsck?

I would expect its safe if if its only checking, and hasn't detected issues and is in the process of fixing them (ie. writing/changing data on the disk), but take care with your interrupt method. You'll find more on interrupts on this thread - https://serverfault.com/questions/57573/how-dangerous-is-it-to-interrupt-an-fsck https://serverfault.com/questions/115426/is-it-safe-to-stop-a-fsck-in-progress etc (but do take into consideration the code & file-system you're running; you didn't provide specific details)

That also suggests there is more going on than a corrupt partition table. There is good possibility that this was caused by failing hardware. You'd better just try to fully reinitialize the disk and repartition/reformat it, then use it cautiously. If issues reappear, then the disk will need to be discarded.

@guiverc it has detected millions of issues. Ctrl+C doesn't do anything

^C is a SIGINT type of interrupt, and is [usually] SAFE; however if the application isn't capable of dealing with that interrupt, either because it's unsafe to stop at that time, or other reason; it maybe unsafe to force higher signal interrupts. The fact that ^C isn't doing anything maybe telling you something; but sorry I don't know the fsck code well enough, let alone what Ubuntu product & release you're using (to look at that exact version you're running to check).  If you have decent backups; why worry; just restore the 2TB of data on a new partition table
